# How do I get eprint, hplain, bibtex, hyperref, and pdflatex to work?

Tags: hyperref, bibtex

After reading https://arxiv.org/help/hypertex/bibstyles/ I thought that I would try to get the bibtex field "eprint" working in my Latex files.  So I downloaded hplain.bst, changed `\bibliographystyle{plain}` to `\bibliographystyle{hplain}`, added the eprint field to a bibtex entry, and ran `pdflatex`.  The eprint field shows up in the pdf file, but is not a link.  Here is a bit of the header from my .tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[hidelinks,pagebackref,pdftex]{hyperref}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run `bibtex`, and might need to run `pdflatex` twice.  Also, tt is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: The page make rather clear that only the last mentioned bib styles support link creation: `utphys.bst`, `utcaps.bst` and `kp.bst`

Comment: @PeterGrill - Yes I ran bibtex and pdflatex several times.

Comment: @egreg - Immediately above that it says "The following bibtex styles have been modified to support an eprint field." and gives a long list, including hplain.  I'll look at kp.bst.

Comment: @PeterGrill - I'll try to give a minimal example tomorrow.  It is a bit late here.

Comment: Supporting an eprint field doesn't mean that an href is built. Indeed, `hplain.bst` just prints it if present (look for `format.eprint` in it).

Comment: @egreg - ok, using kp.bst works.  That immediately morphs my question into "how do I get the formatting of plain.bst and the linking of kp.bst?"  That is - which part of kp.bst do I need to steal?

Comment: @egreg - ok, I think that I might be able to just drop two functions from kp into hplain.  I'll try that and get back to you.  Thanks for pointing out these differences.

Comment: @egreg - ok, I hacked format.eprint and it works. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You might answer to your own question telling how you did it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following egreg's advice I looked at `kp.bst` (linked to from the arXiv page).  This works, in that the arxiv references are now clickable; the `.bst` file automatically generates the correct `\href` commands for `hyperref` from the `bibtex` fields specified by the arXiv.

As I prefer the `plain.bst` style (numbers instead of names, etc) I pulled the relevant functions out of `kp.bst`, dropped them into `hplain.bst`, fiddled a bit, and renamed the mash-up, `hyperplain.bst`.  If there is any interest I can email the file to the arXiv admins.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the function format.eprint as in `utphys.bst`. Then the eprint field should be a link.

Answer (score 0):

utphys.bst and kp.bst are indeed the ones that support clickable URL's. I also struggled a long time before figuring this out. It is indeed indicated in the arxiv page, however a bit vague..